# Div overlaps text in mobile preview

Tags: html, css

I have a div block which contains an image and text:

```
<div style="position: relative; margin-bottom: 90px;"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/4022333/Blog/TOFU/quote.png" style="width: 112px;">
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 78px;">
<p style="font-family: AvenirLight; color: #74818a; font-size: 36px; line-height: 45px; font-style: italic;">“Enabling understanding means being able to communicate effectively”</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I've applied `margin-bottom: 90px;` on the parent div to create a gap between the div and any `p` tags which may be below it.

It works fine on full display, but on mobile, it looks like this:

As you can see, it's overlapping the following `p` tags after the `div`. How can I fix this? Ideally I want a `20px` gap between the parent div and anything outside the div.

Edit:

I feel like my approach is wrong. I.e. if I remove `margin-bottom: 90px;` from the code above, the div will still overlap any following `p` tags:

Comment: Do you have styles that apply only for mobile/small screen sizes? Are there differences in the styles applied to the elements when you inspect them in browser and mobile?

Comment: @Kaddath - Nope, because I feel like my original approach is wrong. I've edited my answer to explain.

Comment: Does the quotation have to be set to position absolute or can you change it to relative?

Comment: I think the reason why this happens is because you assume that the big grey text won't take more than `50px` height (cf `position: absolute; top: 50px;`) But with a smaller screen size text goes to new line more often and gets bigger than this value. If i have anything as a soluition i'll update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why other elements are overlapping your quote element, is because the element which is primarily deciding the height of the element (the `div` which contains the `paragraph`) is having an `absolute` position. An `absolute` positioned element is no longer part of the parent (unless the parent has a `relative` position). So, in this case, because the `div` with the `paragraph` is no longer 'part' of the parent, the parent will only have a height based on the `static`/`relative` positioned elements. Which is the image.

As a solution you can switch the `absolute` position of your `p` element to the `img` element. You know the width and the height of the image, so you can set a `padding` for your paragraph element. In this case the height of the parent div (which is called `.quote-wrapper` in my example) will have the correct height so elements above or below `.quote-wrapper` won't overlap your element.

```css
.quote-wrapper {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.quote-wrapper .quote-image {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Set position to relative so the element won't be overlapped by the image */
.quote-wrapper > p { 
  font-family: AvenirLight; 
  color: #74818a; 
  font-size: 36px; 
  line-height: 45px; 
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 80px 0 0 80px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<div class="quote-wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/4022333/Blog/TOFU/quote.png" class="quote-image" />
  
  <p>
    “Enabling understanding means being able to communicate effectively”
  </p>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `margin-top` inside the tag `p`. I recommend that you put an `id` or `class` for each tag (`div`,`p`...), to make the structure easier and that labels do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your html code this way and add this `media query` to your code.

```
<div style="position: relative; margin-bottom: 90px;"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/4022333/Blog/TOFU/quote.png" style="width: 112px;">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 78px;" class="quotation">
    <p style="font-family: AvenirLight; color: #74818a; font-size: 36px; line-height: 45px; font-style: italic;">“Enabling understanding means being able to communicate effectively”</p>
  </div>
</div>

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .quatation {
    position: static !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that is position absolute on title. i recommended following structure for free hesitate for all resolutions and devices.

```css
.block-quote {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:20px 0 0 70px;
    background:url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/4022333/Blog/TOFU/quote.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'AvenirLight'; 
    color: #74818a; 
    font-size: 36px; 
    line-height: 45px; 
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-quote">
    <h2>“Enabling understanding means being able to communicate effectively”</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sollicitudin vulputate vehicula. Morbi fermentum elit lobortis nibh molestie, nec facilisis elit tempor. Nullam porta lectus erat, et hendrerit diam dictum at. Vestibulum sed enim turpis. Sed vehicula venenatis cursus. Mauris sit amet venenatis velit. Nullam ut purus erat. Nam posuere lorem at est ultrices luctus.</p>
</div>
```